# print a double value (from integer expression) with two decimal places

Tags: c, double

I want to calcuclate the product of 100000, 200000, 300000, using c language, which is 6000000000000000. But I need to answer with a double value with two zeros after decimal point.

I have used following code:

```
long double result = 100000 * 200000 * 300000;
printf("%.2LF", result);
```

expected output:6000000000000000.00
actual output:-593035264.00

Comment: `100000 * 200000 * 300000` performs an integer calculation and overflows.Try `100000.0 * 200000.0 * 300000.0` or `(double)100000 * 200000 * 300000`. Reason? The expression is evaluated without regard to the target variable.

Comment: long double res = 100000.0*200000.0*300000.0;                                                      printf("%.2Lf",res);                                                                                          output :6000000000000000.00                                                                      its working as expected thank you

Comment: @WeatherVane That comment looks like an answer.

Comment: Max range of `double` is `1.79769e+308` -- more than enough for your calculation.

Comment: @Yunnosch - Weather Vane might be sleeping -- why do you write it up?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I expect to be bashed for it (by others, because I agree that WeatherVane probably does not mind...), but I did, let's see.

Comment: @WeatherVane better use `100000.0L * 200000.0L * 300000.0L` since the OP is using `long double`

Comment: It's worth noting, though, that with `float` you get a surprising result (namely `6000000056164352.00`) even if you do it "right".  This is one of those problems where the `float` vs. `double` (or `long double`) precision issue really does matter.

Comment: @phuclv my comment was edited because I dithered between putting `double` and `long double` (the question title says `double`).

Comment: I worked on three questions today. I suspected the other two of being duplicates. My dupe radar failed me. Maybe I need a better one.

Answer (score 1):

*(Making an answer from Weather Vanes comment, to turn this into a Q/A pair, offering to delete if he minds.)*

The expression `100000 * 200000 * 300000` performs an integer calculation and overflows, which explains the seemingly unrelated result value you observe.

Try instead `100000.0 * 200000.0 * 300000.0` or `(double)100000 * 200000 * 300000`.

Reason?
The expression is evaluated without regard to the target variable (and its type),
i.e. you need to force floating point evaluation on the right side of the `=`.

Note Davids helpful comment:
Max range of double is 1.79769e+308 -- more than enough for your calculation.

Comment: No bashing, there is probably a dupe around, but I could find it off-hand. Honest vote for an honest answer. You should be fine, you provided attribution. All good.

Comment: @WeatherVane Just a ping to make you notice I am a little superstitious about using other peoples contribution without permission.

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks I could have posted an answer myself but didn't.